# Use Python's Kivy to change HomeScreen and LockScreen Wallpaper

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make an Android app in python. My app needs a function that's able to change the homescreen and lockscreen wallpapers based on user inputs.

Any ideeas on how could I achieve that with kivy?

Answer (score 1):

Use [pyjnius](https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius) to call the native java API to do that